# Pass arguments based on pattern matchin to function in R

Tags: r, regex, functional-programming

I do have an arbitrary number of R objects I would like to pass as arguments to a function. The naming convention for the objects is "input_\d+", i.e., the string"input_" followed by one or more digits. A static example for only three of these arguments would look like the following:

```
my_function <- function(input_1, input_2, input_3)
```

What would I have to do to make R "look" for all objects satisfying the patter "input_\d+" and pass it to the function (the code of the function can of course handle an arbitrary number of parameters passed).

Any advice would be highly appreciated,

Oli

Comment: How did you wind up in this situation? If you have a bunch of related objects they probably should be in a list, Having a bunch of similarly named objects in your environment is not a very R-like way to track and use data.

Comment: I know; I am using a third party function that accepts a sequence of lists (NOT a list of lists; so as in the above example, "input_1" is a list as is "input_2" and so on); I tired to pass a list of lists that I had "flattened" before (using purrr:flatten), but this does not work.

Comment: Still, do.call makes it easy to turn a list into different parameters. Having the data in lists first is still easier to work with.

Comment: Fair enough. Doing that though, results in the same issue: Each argument results in something like _input_2 = list(name = "my_name", value = "")_ which triggers an error; the correct parameter passed would not have the **input_2 =** part but would just read as **list(name = "my_name", value = "")** Any suggestion on how to achieve that?

Comment: Just unname() the list in do.call

Comment: Ah, okay. cool - that does the trick! Many thanks indeed!

Answer (score 5):

You could use `mget` and `ls` to create a named list of all inputs and pass that list to your function which you might need to modify a bit for that kind of input:

```
my_function(mget(ls(pattern = "^input_\\d+$")))
```

Comment: And use `do.call("my_function", mget(ls(pattern = "^input_\\d+$")))` to pass them as separate parameters if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get` to search by name for an object.

```
input_1 <- 1
input_2 <- 2
input_3 <- 3

my_function <- function(input_1) {
    print(input_1^input_1)
}

for(i in 1:3) {
    foo_1 <- get(paste0("input_", i))
    my_function(foo_1)
}

1
4
27
```